# How to redirect an error 404 to home page without using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, error-handling, http-status-code-404

So I am making a project and I am having a webpage `pagenotfound.php` and
I just want to redirect to this page when a user searches a page that is not present.

I am not using `xampp` or any `.htaccess` like thing.

If anyone has a solution. Do let me know.

Comment: Something is acting as a web server. You need to configure whatever that is to handle 404 errors the way you want. From what you've posted here is impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: i am using php for backend.
it the only thing I am having.

Comment: So you've written a complete web server in PHP? I find it improbable that you could do that and still need to ask this question.